# asp.net Authentication and Users data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, authentication

I am fairly new to ASP.net. I am trying to create a 2 page (`Login.aspx` and `Default.aspx`) application which allows a user to log in to update their details to submit back to the database.

So I have a database with two tables:

1. Accounts - `AccountID` (PK), `Username`, `Password`
2. Users -  `UserID` (PK), `AccountID` (FK),`FirstName`, `Surname`, `Address1`, ...,  `Phone`

I have created the DB authentication model. I just need to know how to use the authenticated users ID to only display their record on the `default.aspx` page.

I guess the SQL will be something similar to the below

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE AccountID = Authenticated User's ID
```

I just don't know how to get the info associated with the authenticated user to pass back to the query.

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication tickets or anything like it?

Comment: Just when you log in look at the persons information and fill in the textboxes with the information. Or are you needing help with it all. Because google has a lot of your questions. "how to pull data from database and display onto textbox" and so on. have you done any research?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1179997.aspx?Get+Username+for+logged+in+user  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am using Forms Authentication, I am just wanting to find out the best method for using the the authenticated users details in a sql query. Even if  its a gridview which just displays the users details. i will be able to figure out the rest I think - it is just how to obtain the users details and then pass it into a sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this for one idea:

```
Select * from Users where AccountID in 
(select AccountID from Accounts where Username='foo' and Password='bar')
```

Course you could stick the AccountID into the Session object for a simpler solution to get the ID.

Comment: Hi JB King - I think this is what I am after, but the part I am unsure about is how to use the session object. Thanks